# Create a task in azure Devops With a powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops

I need your help, I'm trying to create a powershell script that will create a task directly in Azure Devops (Azure Boards -> Work Items).

The problem is that after much research, I haven't found the corresponding module to do this, nor the method to connect to the module, if one exists.

I had the idea of generating a token and using it to connect.

For the moment, I've tried to use the generate token to connect, but it's blocked because I don't know the module for connecting directly to Azure DevOps.

Comment: Did you look at the official REST API documentation that Microsoft provides? Is there something about it that's unclear? Do you not know how to call a REST API in PowerShell? Please ask a **specific** question about an issue you're having.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can reference the PowerShell script sample below to call Azure DevOps REST API to create a **`Task`** type work item.

```
# Convert PAT to a Base64 string.
$pat = "{Personal Access Token}"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

# Set request headers.
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json")

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/`$Task?api-version=7.0"

# Set request body and convert it to JSON type.
$body = @(
    @{
        op = 'add'
        path = '/fields/System.Title'
        value = '{Title}'  # Set the title
    }
    @{
        op = 'add'
        path = '/fields/System.AreaPath'
        value = '{Area Path}'  # Set the Area Path, e.g.: MyProj\\MyArea\\SubArea
    }
    @{
        op = 'add'
        path = '/fields/System.IterationPath'
        value = '{Iteration Path}'  # Set the Iteration Path, e.g.: MyProj\\MyIteration\\SubIteration
    }
) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

# Execute Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet to call the API and convert its response to JSON for better readable.
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

The value of variable "**`$body`**" (request body) also can directly set to be a JSON string like as below.

```
$body = '[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "{Title}"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
        "value": "{Area Path}"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
        "value": "{Iteration Path}"
    }
]'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I've managed to solve my problem!

Comment: @Skydrum, You're welcome. If the answer is helpful for you, maybe, you can accept it. This could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions.

Comment: I'll do that thanks. If you want, I have another question on my page ahah.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Azure DevOps API, and if it's running as a Powershell script in the build you should use the predefined variables. Example:

```
$organizationUrl = $(System.CollectionUri)  
$projectName = $(System.TeamProject )  
$pat = $(System.AccessToken)
$apiVersion = "6.0"
$type = "User Story"
# User Story JSON Payload
    $witFieldsValues = @"
    [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "Test"
      }
    ]
    "@
        
# Azure DevOps REST API URL for creating a work item (user story)
$uri="$organizationUrl/$projectName/_apis/wit/workitems/"+"$"+"$Type"+"?bypassRules=true&api-version=$apiVersion"
    
$creationResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $witFieldsValues -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{
            Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$pat")) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so I tried with my information. Except I get this error. 

After checking all the information is correct, I don't understand why it's telling me it can't find it. The URL is good though, and I took the URL when I'm in my organization before choosing the projects.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://MyURLOrganization/MyProject/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version=6.0'."}}
Au caractère Ligne:17 : 13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers @{
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: Have you enabled the OAuth token for the build? Have you added a print to ensure all variables are set properly? Please take the printed url and paste it in your browser, you should also see there your results.

Comment: yes, everything's already been done and tried. In fact, when I put the url in https://dev.azure.com/Myorganization/ it doesn't take what's after dev.azure.com/ So it doesn't take my organization when it retrieves the variable in $uri. I don't understand why.

Comment: Try using this instead: System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri

Comment: the problem is that the script is executed locally on my PC, and not in a pipeline

Comment: I've made a small change, please try it out :) To test locally just replace the variables defined at the top with the actual ones.